# Paho MQTT in browser with jupyterlite

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, pyodide, jupyterlite

I'm attempting to run Paho MQTT in a browser using jupyterlite and pyodide. I was able to install paho using micropip (see example in link below). But the paho client times out when attempting to connect. I tried using websockets but this also failed with timeout. I tried ports 443, 9001 but that failed.

> client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id, transport='websockets')

Broker is https://mqtt.eclipseprojects.io/

Here is the notebook [example](https://discoverling.github.io/morse-decoder/lab/index.html) (see morse_decoder.ipynb) which you can run on a browser.

I import as follows:

```
import pyodide_kernel
import micropip
await micropip.install(['numpy', 'scikit-learn', 'https://www.piwheels.org/simple/paho-mqtt/paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=c44b3dd1b298894c44e3e842f7b0ca3ebe01f628a6f229c881b2324613d7bba7'])
pyodide_kernel.__version__
```

Client code:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client

# MQTT settings
client_id = f'publish-{random.randint(0, 1000)}'

def connect_mqtt(broker, port):
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)
    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id, transport='websockets')
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You need to include a lot more detail in the question. e.g. What broker are you connecting to? Has it been configured to support MQTT over websockets?

Comment: broker = 'mqtt.eclipseprojects.io'

As per https://mqtt.eclipseprojects.io/, it seems to expect port 443 for WebSockets. Port 80 doesn't work.

Comment: Forgot to mention, all the code is public in that example link.

Comment: Yes, but questions should contain all the required information, links should only be for extended reference.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible because your code will be running under pyodide which does not support [sockets](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/wasm-constraints.html#included-but-not-working-modules) (which paho requires).